# What's a good way to parse an input into a command, parameters, and values for those parameters?

Tags: python, parsing, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot using the discord.py module (in Python) that is able to parse out commands. The trouble I'm having is that I want each command to be able to have parameters, denoted by a "-".
For example if someone sent "sm!poll -m='Test' -s" the bot should return "{user} asked: Test". If someone sent "sm!poll -m='Test-2'" the bot should reply with "@everyone {user} asked: Test-2"

Therein lies the problem. I'm using - to denote a parameter, but I also want to be able to use it inside of the poll that the bot sends. Here's the code I have so far:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('sm!'):
        cmd=(message.content+'! ').split('!')[1]#finds everything after sm!
        param=(cmd+"- ").split('-')[1:]#         separates out all of the parameters
        paramDict={}#                            makes a dictionary to hold the parameters
        for i in param:
            temp=i.split('=')#                 tries to split each parameter into a parameter and a value
            try:
                temp[1]
            except IndexError:#                if there is no value, sets the value to true
                temp.append(True)
            paramDict[temp[0]]=temp[1]
```

The end goal is to have a variable called "cmd" that I can use startswith on, and a dictionary full of all of the parameters in the message.

Basically, if - is between quotes, ignore it, but if it outside of quotes, treat it as a parameter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Basically, if - is between quotes, ignore it, but if it outside of quotes, treat it as a parameter." Try `shlex.split` first (`shlex` is in the standard library) and see if it's good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel will do

Comment: After you split the command using `shlex`, you might want to consider using `argparse` to handle the options. (Note that `argparse` is not limited to parsing `sys.argv`. You can supply the list to parse as an argument to `parse_args`; it only uses `sys.argv` if no argument is provided.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `on_message()` function to manage your commands is not the right way to do.

I recommend you to use the [`Commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands) extension.

This is how you're supposed to import it :

```py
from discord.ext import commands
```

### Commands in `__main__`

If you want your commands to be in your `__main__` file, this is how you would create a command :

```py
# In __main__.py

@bot.command()
async def hello(context, my_arg):
    await context.send(f"Hello {my_arg}")
```

Usage :

```
.hello world
```

Output :

```
Hello world
```

### Commands out of `__main__`

Or, if you want your command to be stored in an external file and to manage it as an **object**, you can use the discord.py extension system.
Your command will be written inside an object called `Cog`.

This is how you do it :

```
# Inside my_cog.py

from discord.ext import commands


class MyCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def my_command(self, context):
        """
            DO SOMETHING
        """

# OUT OF THE CLASS
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCommand(bot))
```

Now you have to tell your bot where he can find the command you just wrote :

```
# In __main__.py

import discord
import asyncio
import os

from discord.ext import commands


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # Private
        self.__TOKEN  = os.environ["YOUR_TOKEN"]       # Safety first, use os.environ !
        self.__prefix = ['.']                          # You can store multiple prefixes
        self.__extensions = ["extensions.my_command"]  # Path to my_command.py file

    def run(self):
        bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=self.__prefix)

        """
            YOUR STUFF
        """
    
        # Load your extensions
        for extension in self.__extensions
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

            bot.load_extension(extension)

        client.run(self.__TOKEN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

This is how you manage commands using `discord.py`.

I highly recommend you to read the doc' ;)

Hope it helped ! Have fun working with `discord.py` !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help @KarlKnechtel!

I used shlex.split to separate the message by spaces, keeping anything inside of quotes intact.

```
import shlex
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('sm!'):
        cmd=message.content.split('!',1)[1]
        sep=shlex.split(cmd)
        params={}
        params['cmd']=sep[0]
        for i in sep[1:]:
            try:
                params[i.split('=',1)[0]]=i.split('=',1)[1]
            except IndexError:
                params[i.split('=',1)[0]]=True
```